# centering a table in a row of main table

Tags: css, html

I am working on a page where we have show all the parent records with a '+' sign in the 1st cell of each row, clicking on which the the child records (which is another table) should be shown below the parent row(done using jQuery). I am able to show the child row, but I am unable to center the child table below the parent row.

```
<table border='2'>
    <tr>
        <th>Parent Column 1</th>
        <th>Parent column 2</th>
        <th>Parent Column 3</th>
        <th>Parent column 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item 1</td>
        <td>item 2</td>
        <td>item 3</td>
        <td>item 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <table border='1' style="text-align:center;position:relative;">
            <tr>
                <th>Child Column 1</th>
                <th>Child column 2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 1</td>
                <td>item 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item 1</td>
        <td>item 2</td>
        <td>item 3</td>
        <td>item 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can see the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cmXS6/)

For some I am unable to show the 3rd row in the table in the fiddle as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have `<tr>` with no `<td>` so you  have a wrong HTML structure. So you need to add `<td colspan="4" align="center">CHILD TABLE CODE HERE</td>`

Check in [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cmXS6/6/)

So like that:

```
<table border='2'>
<tr>
    <th>Parent Column 1</th>
    <th>Parent column 2</th>
    <th>Parent Column 3</th>
    <th>Parent column 4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
    <td>item 2</td>
    <td>item 3</td>
    <td>item 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>Child Column 1</th>
            <th>Child column 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 1</td>
            <td>item 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
    <td>item 2</td>
    <td>item 3</td>
    <td>item 4</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

wrapped your nested table inside  and applied an inline style to your nested table of `margin: 0 auto;` which is what centers your nested table

```
<table border='2'>
    <tr>
        <th>Parent Column 1</th>
        <th>Parent column 2</th>
        <th>Parent Column 3</th>
        <th>Parent column 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item 1</td>
        <td>item 2</td>
        <td>item 3</td>
        <td>item 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center">
        <table border='1' style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <tr>
                <th>Child Column 1</th>
                <th>Child column 2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 1</td>
                <td>item 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item 1</td>
        <td>item 2</td>
        <td>item 3</td>
        <td>item 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```